# Why does my Restore-SPSite take all day?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, backup, restore

This is a fairly generic question, I know.  But, the .bak of my live SharePoint Foundation 2010 site is only 22GB.  From what I'm reading, that's not a lot.  Yet, when I run the following command in PowerShell:

```
Restore-SPSite http://myserver/ -Path C:\SharePointFiles\SiteBackup.bak -Force
```

...it typically takes over a day to do the restore.  Not only that, but 60% of the time, I come back the following day to see this error:

> Restore-SPSite : The site collection could not be restored. If this
>   problem persists, please make sure the content d atabases are
>   available and have sufficient free space.

What can I do to make my site restores have a better chance than a crap-shoot?  I've found that I do have more luck restoring my site to a "vanilla" state before doing this actual restore, but... I just wish there was a way to restore a site that doesn't involve praying in order to avoid wasting a whole day watching an ill-fated restore attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the system resources, But a site with 22gb should not take that much time. one more thing it also depends on the network. If you run the restore during the working hours, that's also slow down the process.

As my experience, any site collection is greater than 20GB should be moved into own content Database. that's a way it makes life easier. in your case, if you move the Site collection into own content DB, then for recovery

- You have to perform the backup of the content DB
- You have to restore the Content Database
- then attach that DB to the web application.

The other error you are getting, Becuase your restore operation timed out and throws the error.

Comment: So, when you say "perform backup [and then restore] of/to content database," are you doing that in SQL Management Studio (as in, an actual database backup), or are you doing that in Central Admin... what utility(ies) are you using to do the backup/restore?

Comment: i am using the SQL backup and restore.

Comment: If I use SSMS to do the restore, do I have to have a .bak that was made from a SSMS backup?  Meaning, if my SharePoint admin gave me a .bak created in CA, do I need to go back and request a SSMS backup in order to do this?

Comment: You need a SQL backup of the content db not shrepoint, in order to restore it in SQL server. you have to get from your sql admin or do it yourself

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot.  I just put in a request for our DBA to build a raw .bak of the SQL DB.

Comment: The other thing to watch out for is that SharePoint can't deal with 2 sites having the same ID on the same farm, so if you are restoring a previous backup you have to get rid of (detach the old content DB) first.

Comment: Well, the backup is of our live site on another server.  Essentially, I have a massive PowerShell script that I want to run on a straight restore of the production site before running it on the actual site.  So, I just need a restore of our live site on my local machine.

Comment: @NotVonKaiser any references? I have observed the behaviour before, but I would like to know more on it!

Comment: @nisarg...site collection id and content db id stored in the config db, so if you try to attach the same content db within same farm even with different web app, 1st you get the error, a db with this id already in the farm, ...lets say if you change the db id using assign new id...then you will able to attach the db but still u will not see the site.

Comment: For the record, I got a .bak through SQL of the content database.  I did a restore into SQL, then through CA I built a new site and entered the new DB into the field... and everything worked swimmingly.  This turned a 1-day task that had a 40% chance of success into pretty much a sure-fire method that only takes 20 minutes.

Comment: Yup, that's it...happy solve your issue...enjoy